# i want to check the bluetooth state on the event of onClick button. is it possible to do so? here are part of my code

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Here are some of the code i've been working on.
i wanted to check the bluetooth state on the event of button clicked but it seems theres a problem with this code which i can't figured out as when i'm trying to run the app its always "unfortunately... has stopped. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
package com.example.android.bluetoothattendance;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class menu extends AppCompatActivity {

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}

public void takeAtt(View view) {
    //to check bluetooth state
    if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        //proceed to next activity if bluetooth is enable
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, takeAttendance.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
    else{
        //enable bluetooth is bluetooth currently disable
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you post your `logcat` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks fine except I suppose your `bluetoothAdapter` could be null. It will return null if Bluetooth is not support on your device. Bluetooth is not supported on Android Emulator.

So if you're testing on emulator the app will crash

Comment: ah i see, i've never try to run it on my device yet. i appreciate that Rainmaker. thank you so much.

Comment: if it really was the problem , please let me know and kindly accept the answer by hitting the arrow to the left of my answer to let others know that it is the solution)